# Unknown resultsetmapping Error Springboot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I am working with Springboot JPA with Hibernate as persistent provider. I am getting below exception while running the application. what am I missing in the code?

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [TaxelMapping1]
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [TaxelMapping1]

This first time I am working with Data Jpa.

This is my repository code:

```
@Repository
public class TaxonomyRepoImpl implements TaxonomyRepo {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TaxonomyRepoImpl.class);
    
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager taxonomyEntityManagerFactory;

    @Override
    public List<TaxelDTO> loadTaxels() {
        
        logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>loadTaxels");
        
        logger.info(">>>>>>>>>>>>>loadTaxels taxonomyEntityManagerFactory = " + taxonomyEntityManagerFactory);
        
        List<TaxelDTO> taxelList = new ArrayList();
        Map<Integer, TaxelDTO> taxelsMap = new HashMap();
        
        //StoredProcedureQuery query =  taxonomyEntityManagerFactory.createStoredProcedureQuery("GetAllTaxels", "TaxelMapping1");
        
        String sqlQuery = " SELECT t.TaxCount, tl.TaxelID " +
                "      ,TaxelName " +
                "      ,tl.TaxelGroupID " +
                "      ,Version " +
                "      ,Revision " +
                "      ,CreatedFor " +
                "      ,TaxIDRangeStart " +
                "      ,TaxIDRangeEnd " +
                "      ,IsSetting " +
                "      ,IsEvent " +
                "      ,IsCategorical " +
                "      ,IsContinuousInteger " +
                "      ,IsMoney " +
                "      ,IsFloat " +
                "      ,IsInterval " +
                "      ,NumericLowerLimit " +
                "      ,NumericUpperLimit " +
                "      ,NumberOfLevels " +
                "      ,DisplayName " +
                "      ,DisplayHint " +
                "      ,DisplayClass " +
                "      ,DisplayPriority " +
                "      ,tg.TaxelGroupName " +
                "      ,IsPersonLevel " +
                "      ,IsNonEncounter " +
                "      ,IsTPF " +
                "     ,IsProviderLevel " +
                "     ,IsUniqueValue " +
                     
                " from Taxel tl " +
                " JOIN TaxelGroup tg on tl.TaxelGroupID = tg.TaxelGroupID  " +
                " LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as TaxCount,TaxelID FROM Tax Group by TaxelID) t on t.TaxelID = tl.TaxelID ";
        
        Query query = taxonomyEntityManagerFactory.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, "TaxelMapping1");

        try {
            taxelList = (List<TaxelDTO>) query.getResultList();
            int size = taxelList.size();
            logger.info("<<<<<<<<<<, taxelResults size = " + size);
            
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>loadTaxels Exception e = " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return taxelList;
    }
}
```

My Configuration Class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.merative.marketscan.txp.repository.taxonomydb",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "taxonomyEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "taxonomyTransactionManager"
)

public class TaxonomyDBConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.taxonomy.datasource")
    public DataSource taxonomyDatasource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean taxonomyEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(taxonomyDatasource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.merative.marketscan.txp.entity.taxonomydb");

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter
                = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager taxonomyTransactionManager() {

        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
                taxonomyEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

My Dto Class:

```
package com.merative.marketscan.txp.model.taxonomydb;

public class TaxelDTO {

    private Integer taxelId;
    private String taxelName;
    private Integer taxelGroupId;
    private String version;
    private String revision;
    private String createdFor;
    private Integer taxIdRangeStart;
    private Integer taxIdRangeEnd;
    private Boolean isSetting;
    private Boolean isEvent;
    private Boolean isCategorical;
    private Boolean isContinuousInteger;
    private Boolean isMoney;
    private Boolean isFloat;
    private Boolean isInterval;
    private Double numericLowerLimit;
    private Double numericUpperLimit;
    private Integer numberOfLevels;
    private String displayName;
    private String displayHint;
    private String displayClass;
    private Integer displayPriority;
    private String taxelGroupName;
    private Boolean isPersonLevel;
    private Boolean isNonEncounter;
    private Boolean isTPF;
    private Integer taxCount;
    private Boolean isProviderLevel;
    private Boolean isUniqueValue;

    public TaxelDTO(Integer taxCount, Integer taxelId, String taxelName, Integer taxelGroupId, String version, String revision,
            String createdFor, Integer taxIdRangeStart, Integer taxIdRangeEnd, Boolean isSetting, Boolean isEvent,
            Boolean isCategorical, Boolean isContinuousInteger, Boolean isMoney, Boolean isFloat, Boolean isInterval,
            Double numericLowerLimit, Double numericUpperLimit, Integer numberOfLevels, String displayName,
            String displayHint, String displayClass, Integer displayPriority, String taxelGroupName,
            Boolean isPersonLevel, Boolean isNonEncounter, Boolean isTPF,  Boolean isProviderLevel,
            Boolean isUniqueValue) {
        super();
        this.taxCount = taxCount;
        this.taxelId = taxelId;
        this.taxelName = taxelName;
        this.taxelGroupId = taxelGroupId;
        this.version = version;
        this.revision = revision;
        this.createdFor = createdFor;
        this.taxIdRangeStart = taxIdRangeStart;
        this.taxIdRangeEnd = taxIdRangeEnd;
        this.isSetting = isSetting;
        this.isEvent = isEvent;
        this.isCategorical = isCategorical;
        this.isContinuousInteger = isContinuousInteger;
        this.isMoney = isMoney;
        this.isFloat = isFloat;
        this.isInterval = isInterval;
        this.numericLowerLimit = numericLowerLimit;
        this.numericUpperLimit = numericUpperLimit;
        this.numberOfLevels = numberOfLevels;
        this.displayName = displayName;
        this.displayHint = displayHint;
        this.displayClass = displayClass;
        this.displayPriority = displayPriority;
        this.taxelGroupName = taxelGroupName;
        this.isPersonLevel = isPersonLevel;
        this.isNonEncounter = isNonEncounter;
        this.isTPF = isTPF;
        
        this.isProviderLevel = isProviderLevel;
        this.isUniqueValue = isUniqueValue;
    }

    public Integer getTaxelId() {
        return taxelId;
    }

    public void setTaxelId(Integer taxelId) {
        this.taxelId = taxelId;
    }

    public String getTaxelName() {
        return taxelName;
    }

    public void setTaxelName(String taxelName) {
        this.taxelName = taxelName;
    }

    public Integer getTaxelGroupId() {
        return taxelGroupId;
    }

    public void setTaxelGroupId(Integer taxelGroupId) {
        this.taxelGroupId = taxelGroupId;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public String getCreatedFor() {
        return createdFor;
    }

    public void setCreatedFor(String createdFor) {
        this.createdFor = createdFor;
    }

    public Integer getTaxIdRangeStart() {
        return taxIdRangeStart;
    }

    public void setTaxIdRangeStart(Integer taxIdRangeStart) {
        this.taxIdRangeStart = taxIdRangeStart;
    }

    public Integer getTaxIdRangeEnd() {
        return taxIdRangeEnd;
    }

    public void setTaxIdRangeEnd(Integer taxIdRangeEnd) {
        this.taxIdRangeEnd = taxIdRangeEnd;
    }

    public Boolean getIsSetting() {
        return isSetting;
    }

    public void setIsSetting(Boolean isSetting) {
        this.isSetting = isSetting;
    }

    public Boolean getIsEvent() {
        return isEvent;
    }

    public void setIsEvent(Boolean isEvent) {
        this.isEvent = isEvent;
    }

    public Boolean getIsCategorical() {
        return isCategorical;
    }

    public void setIsCategorical(Boolean isCategorical) {
        this.isCategorical = isCategorical;
    }

    public Boolean getIsContinuousInteger() {
        return isContinuousInteger;
    }

    public void setIsContinuousInteger(Boolean isContinuousInteger) {
        this.isContinuousInteger = isContinuousInteger;
    }

    public Boolean getIsMoney() {
        return isMoney;
    }

    public void setIsMoney(Boolean isMoney) {
        this.isMoney = isMoney;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFloat() {
        return isFloat;
    }

    public void setIsFloat(Boolean isFloat) {
        this.isFloat = isFloat;
    }

    public Boolean getIsInterval() {
        return isInterval;
    }

    public void setIsInterval(Boolean isInterval) {
        this.isInterval = isInterval;
    }

    public Double getNumericLowerLimit() {
        return numericLowerLimit;
    }

    public void setNumericLowerLimit(Double numericLowerLimit) {
        this.numericLowerLimit = numericLowerLimit;
    }

    public Double getNumericUpperLimit() {
        return numericUpperLimit;
    }

    public void setNumericUpperLimit(Double numericUpperLimit) {
        this.numericUpperLimit = numericUpperLimit;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfLevels() {
        return numberOfLevels;
    }

    public void setNumberOfLevels(Integer numberOfLevels) {
        this.numberOfLevels = numberOfLevels;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDisplayHint() {
        return displayHint;
    }

    public void setDisplayHint(String displayHint) {
        this.displayHint = displayHint;
    }

    public String getDisplayClass() {
        return displayClass;
    }

    public void setDisplayClass(String displayClass) {
        this.displayClass = displayClass;
    }

    public Integer getDisplayPriority() {
        return displayPriority;
    }

    public void setDisplayPriority(Integer displayPriority) {
        this.displayPriority = displayPriority;
    }

    public String getTaxelGroupName() {
        return taxelGroupName;
    }

    public void setTaxelGroupName(String taxelGroupName) {
        this.taxelGroupName = taxelGroupName;
    }

    public Boolean getIsPersonLevel() {
        return isPersonLevel;
    }

    public void setIsPersonLevel(Boolean isPersonLevel) {
        this.isPersonLevel = isPersonLevel;
    }

    public Boolean getIsNonEncounter() {
        return isNonEncounter;
    }

    public void setIsNonEncounter(Boolean isNonEncounter) {
        this.isNonEncounter = isNonEncounter;
    }

    public Boolean getIsTPF() {
        return isTPF;
    }

    public void setIsTPF(Boolean isTPF) {
        this.isTPF = isTPF;
    }

    public Integer getTaxCount() {
        return taxCount;
    }

    public void setTaxCount(Integer taxCount) {
        this.taxCount = taxCount;
    }

    public Boolean getIsProviderLevel() {
        return isProviderLevel;
    }

    public void setIsProviderLevel(Boolean isProviderLevel) {
        this.isProviderLevel = isProviderLevel;
    }

    public Boolean getIsUniqueValue() {
        return isUniqueValue;
    }

    public void setIsUniqueValue(Boolean isUniqueValue) {
        this.isUniqueValue = isUniqueValue;
    }
    
}
```

Entity Class:

```
package com.merative.marketscan.txp.entity.taxonomydb;

@Entity

@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="TaxelMapping1", 
        classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = TaxelDTO.class, 
        columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxCount", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxelId", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxelName", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxelGroupId", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "version", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "revision", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "createdFor", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxIdRangeStart", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxIdRangeEnd", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isSetting", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isEvent", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isCategorical", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isContinuousInteger", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isMoney", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isFloat", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isInterval", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "numericLowerLimit", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "numericUpperLimit", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "numberOfLevels", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "displayName", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "displayHint", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "displayClass", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "displayPriority", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "taxelGroupName", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isPersonLevel", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isNonEncounter", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isTPF", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isProviderLevel", type = Boolean.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "isUniqueValue", type = Boolean.class)
                
}))
public class Taxel {
    
    
    @Id
    private Integer taxelId;
    
    
    @Column(name = "TaxelName")
    private String taxelName;
    
    @Column(name = "TaxelGroupID")
    private Integer taxelGroupId;
    
    @Column(name = "Version")
    private String vesion;
    
    @Column(name = "Revision")
    private String revision;
    
    @Column(name = "CreatedFor")
    private String createdFor;
    
    @Column(name = "TaxIDRangeStart")
    private Integer taxIdRangeStart;

    public Integer getTaxelId() {
        return taxelId;
    }

    public void setTaxelId(Integer taxelId) {
        this.taxelId = taxelId;
    }

    public String getTaxelName() {
        return taxelName;
    }

    public void setTaxelName(String taxelName) {
        this.taxelName = taxelName;
    }

    public Integer getTaxelGroupId() {
        return taxelGroupId;
    }

    public void setTaxelGroupId(Integer taxelGroupId) {
        this.taxelGroupId = taxelGroupId;
    }

    public String getVesion() {
        return vesion;
    }

    public void setVesion(String vesion) {
        this.vesion = vesion;
    }

    public String getRevision() {
        return revision;
    }

    public void setRevision(String revision) {
        this.revision = revision;
    }

    public String getCreatedFor() {
        return createdFor;
    }

    public void setCreatedFor(String createdFor) {
        this.createdFor = createdFor;
    }

    public Integer getTaxIdRangeStart() {
        return taxIdRangeStart;
    }

    public void setTaxIdRangeStart(Integer taxIdRangeStart) {
        this.taxIdRangeStart = taxIdRangeStart;
    }
}
```

My SqlServer query is:

```
String sqlQuery = " SELECT t.TaxCount, tl.TaxelID " +
            "      ,TaxelName " +
            "      ,tl.TaxelGroupID " +
            "      ,Version " +
            "      ,Revision " +
            "      ,CreatedFor " +
            "      ,TaxIDRangeStart " +
            "      ,TaxIDRangeEnd " +
            "      ,IsSetting " +
            "      ,IsEvent " +
            "      ,IsCategorical " +
            "      ,IsContinuousInteger " +
            "      ,IsMoney " +
            "      ,IsFloat " +
            "      ,IsInterval " +
            "      ,NumericLowerLimit " +
            "      ,NumericUpperLimit " +
            "      ,NumberOfLevels " +
            "      ,DisplayName " +
            "      ,DisplayHint " +
            "      ,DisplayClass " +
            "      ,DisplayPriority " +
            "      ,tg.TaxelGroupName " +
            "      ,IsPersonLevel " +
            "      ,IsNonEncounter " +
            "      ,IsTPF " +
            "     ,IsProviderLevel " +
            "     ,IsUniqueValue " +
                 
            " from Taxel tl " +
            " JOIN TaxelGroup tg on tl.TaxelGroupID = tg.TaxelGroupID  " +
            " LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) as TaxCount,TaxelID FROM Tax Group by TaxelID) t on t.TaxelID = tl.TaxelID ";
```

Comment: My Repo Interface:

Comment: My Repo Interface:
@Repository
@Transactional("taxonomyTransactionManager")
public interface TaxonomyRepo {

 List<TaxelDTO> loadTaxels();
}

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Use the [edit] link

Comment: Can any one please give some suggestion i am struggling with it since some days and not able to resolve it. Its vary critical please suggest.